# Map scale based on altitude

Tags: openlayers, scale, altitude

I'm either missing something or failing at some basic math here, but is it possible to calculate the map resolution (map units/pixel) based on altitude (from sea level)? I have center coordinates and projection.

Comment: Your pixel size will not depend on altitude. It would depend more on Latitude.

Comment: @Vesanto only with certain projections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents from the conversation following the previous answer: from what @Thiatt explains, he wants to define resolution as the apparent size of a pixel, viewed from an altitude *A* (which is actually a good definition). So, this is a simple trigonometry problem.

First, you have to set an "angular swath" (or "field of view", I don't know the english correct term) *α*, which would be the maximum view angle (from the nadir). Let's say α = 45°, but you can adjust it depending on the resolution you want.

Now, I will assume that the max horizontal and vertical extent of your map, from the center, is N = 500 px (i.e. your map size is 1000 x 1000 px).

Then, if R is the resolution (in m/px), you have the following relationship:

[image: formula]

Thus:

[image: formula]

With α = 45° and N = 500 px, you get R = 0.2 m/px at the altitude A = 100 m, and R = 2 m/px for A = 1000 m. If R is too low for your application, increase α in the formula.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I had looked into that before, but got confused for two reasons, one being I could never wrap my head around trigonometry, and the other being I couldn't see where I could pull the angle α from with the information I had. I still can't specify a resolution based on an altitude because the map width itself depends on the resolution for OpenLayers, but your comment definitely helped in steering me in a workable direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Map resolution is in no way related to the altitude, `ESRI` defines resolution as

> The detail with which a map depicts the location and shape of geographic features. The larger the map scale, the higher the possible resolution. As scale decreases, resolution diminishes and feature boundaries must be smoothed, simplified, or not shown at all; for example, small areas may have to be represented as points.

While map scale [refers to the relationship (or ratio) between distance on a map and the corresponding distance on the ground.](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/national-location-information/topographic-maps-data/basics/what-is-map-scale)

Comment: Then what would a functionality that allows you to specify starting viewpoint with latitude, longitude and altitude mean?

Comment: Starting viewpoints are generally specified with latitude, longitude and zoom levels, where exactly did you encounter altitude?

Comment: It is an app requirement from our client.

Comment: If you are specifying the starting viewpoint on a mapping application with latitude, longitude and altitude then it might be using altitude as the height of your viewpoint ( but I'm not sure how that works).

Can you post a sample?

Comment: It is not, I'm using OpenLayers as the map library. OpenLayers uses resolution to specify the zoom level. Our client wants the users to be able to specify the zoom in meters from sea level, so I need to find a way to turn one into the other.

Comment: You could try using the pixel size in meters to specify zoom levels http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels but I'm not aware of any relationship between zoom levels and meters from sea level (I honestly don't think there is one)

Comment: Resolution for OpenLayers is map units per pixel. I think the definition of resolution you gave me is different, no?

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication somewhere, because "meters from sea level" does not make any sense to me in resolution context.

Comment: If resolution is how many meters are represented in each pixel, then I would assume the farther your "viewport" is from the map, the higher this number will be (more meters in one pixel).

Comment: @Thiatt that makes no sense at all. Think of it like this, if you are looking at a square on the side of a wall (your pixel) and it is 2x2feet (your resolution) whether you view if from 1 meter away from the wall or 50 meters away from the wall (your "viewport" distance) the square will remain 2x2feet, its resolution has no relation with the distance you are viewing it from.

Comment: Using your analogy, OpenLayers refers to resolution as "how many world feet can you see through this 2x2 feet square". So the same 2x2 feet square will show more of the world inside it the farther it is from the actual world.